# What is it called when at university there are two subjects being held at the same time?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

For example, I need to enroll in two different courses at university, but there is a schedule in which both are held. 
Is it an 'overlapped schedule' or something similar?
Is there a proper expression for this purpose?

Answer (score 42):

In my experience the most common idiom is

> a **scheduling conflict**

This can apply anywhere, not just to academics.  For example, in a work email:

> Hi Jim, can we move our meeting to 3pm?  I have a **scheduling conflict** with another meeting at our original time.  Thanks.

Note this assumes you want to participate in both events.  If these classes just happen to be at the same time, then [Laurel's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/228388/42184) of "simultaneous" is more accurate.

Comment: The great thing about **conflict** is it can work as multiple parts of speech.  Noun: as above.  Verb: "These classes *conflict* with each other."  Gerund/Adj: "*Conflicting* classes make it harder to design my schedule."

Comment: @April It's probably worth pointing out that the noun (CON-flict) and the verb/participle (con-FLICT/con-FLIC-ting) are pronounced differently. Here's a source appropriate for ELL: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/conflict

Answer (score 24):

I had this happen to me a lot at University, and the word in use then was 'clash'.

> Oh no, I have another timetable **clash** this semester.

or

> I have to see my tutor; plant biology **clashes** with statistics on Thursdays

Comment: 'scheduling conflict' and 'simultaneous' etc are rather dry and don't convey the emotion of not being able to get to a class you paid for. 'Clash' does a much better job.

Comment: A comma seems insufficient in the second example.

Comment: @Strawberry: Indeed. It's a comma splice. It should be either a semicolon or a period.

Answer (score 8):

The classes are **simultaneous**:

> occurring, operating, or done at the same time.  — [Lexico/Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/simultaneous)

Here's an example in use (from a [tango site](http://nepatango.com/Workshop.html)):

> Saturday July 25th
>
> 1-2:15pm w/Anais - Beginner Level - Embellishments for the leader and follower
>   1-2:15pm w/Carlos - Intermediate Level - Paradas/Barridas
>   (above classes are simultaneous)

Comment: Great.  Now I want to go take those tango classes.  Shame I live on the other side of the continent  :)

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, you are saying

> The "Microeconomics - ECON101" class is scheduled at 11 am, and so is "Introduction to Psychology - PSYC101".

Is that correct?

Well, may be the easiest way to say this would be

> Both Econ101 and Psyc101 classes are scheduled at the same time.

You could also say

> ... my Econ101 class **coincides** with my Psyc101 class ...

From Cambridge (1) and Collins (2) "coincide" means

> (1) to come together in position or happen at or near the same time 
>   (2) If one event coincides with another, they happen at the same time.

There are many ways to say this (you have not provided an example sentence)

You could use the word **"concurrent"** meaning "happening at the same time" (Cambridge)

> ... Econ101 and Psyc101 classes run **concurrently** ...

As Andrew mentioned, you can also say

> There is a **scheduling conflict** [or schedule conflict] ...

*A scheduling conflict occurs when two (or more) subjects are offered at the same time, and the student must make a choice between the two.* - How to Build the Master Schedule in 10 Easy Steps (2008).

Comment: I think "scheduled at the same time" is the best choice even though it is a bit wordy.  Scheduling conflict is OK, but I would say that you have a scheduling conflict rather than the classes have a scheduling conflict.  Simultaneous can be tricky as well.  I could see that used to mean two classes that are offered during the same semester, but not necessarily at the same time/date.

Answer (score 2):

I would express it by saying that the classes are "in conflict."

> Oh no! My math class is in conflict with the English class I wanted to take.

Or...

> That job would be a conflict with another commitment I have.

Answer (score 1):

Overlapping schedule is not a bad phrase.  (Furthermore, neither are some of the other good answers.)  That is certainly a phrase that is used.  Although, if you know exactly how many items are having overlapping schedules, it may be a bit more common to say a more specific term, **"double-booked**" or "**triple-booked**".

Comment: I've never heard "double-scheduled", although it is similar to the common term "double-booked". (BrE speaker from southern England, for context.)

Comment: I agree with IMSoP that "double-booked" would be the more common version of this term for me. (Midwest US)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, "double-scheduled" and "triple-scheduled" was not what I meant.  I did mean "double-booked".  I definitely wrote down the phrases very wrong, not matching the common term I had in mind.  I thought of just leaving things since Brain Minton has now stated the correct term, but the old version of my answer felt very inaccurate before I corrected my error, and I didn't want to leave that looking so inaccurate.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you are scheduled to be in two classes (or appointments in general) at the same time, you'd describe yourself as **[double-booked](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double-book)**.