# When two classes are held simultaneously

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was wondering which sentence below sounds more idiomatic in **AE** when two classes coincide with one another:

> Oh, no! My math class ......... with biology class! 
> **a)** is in conflict with 
> **b)** conflicts 
> **c)** coincides

I have already read the [similar thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/228384/what-is-it-called-when-at-university-there-are-two-subjects-being-held-at-the-sa), but unfortunately I didn’t find it helpful.

Comment: i would personally use "clashes", as one of the answers in the link also points out

Comment: Well @flumperious “clash” in this sense is normally used in BE, while I need an AE equivalent for that.

Comment: my apologies, i wasn't aware of that difference in AE. otherwise i would say "conflicts"

Comment: conflicts is right but not colloquial.

Comment: All of them are grammatically correct but not what I would call *idiomatic*.  I would just say "is at the same time as biology class".

Comment: What about the other thread is not useful  It gives an answer "conflict" and "clash" Both are fine (but clash seems to be UK specific)

Comment: What about “X is at the same time **with** Y class” @stangdon?

Comment: @A-friend "at the same time **as**" is much more common than "at the same time **with**": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+the+same+time+as%2Cat+the+same+time+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20same%20time%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20same%20time%20with%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of those (even ignoring the duplicate *with* in A), the best option is B.

For example, according to [Duke University](https://registrar.duke.edu/time-conflicts):

> Instructors should not grant students permission to leave class early or arrive late when their class **conflicts with** another on the student’s schedule.

Option A (after removing the extra *with*) isn't natural because it makes it sound like the classes are literally fighting each other.

Option C is a little bit harder to analyze beyond *people don't say this*. Still, I think the problem with it is that it's just not forceful enough. For example, note how the coinciding is a good thing in the following [church announcement](http://etchurch.org/churchevents/2019/12/4/new-membership-class):

> Childcare is available during this time, since the class coincides with our regular Wednesday evening activities.

---

Of course these aren't the only options, *happens at the same time as* and similar are also acceptable:

> How do I take two college courses that are scheduled at the same time? — [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-take-two-college-courses-that-are-scheduled-at-the-same-time)

Also, I (being American) would understand "clash" in this context but wouldn't be likely to use it, so characterizing it as non-American English seems accurate (it seems to be used in [Australian English](https://studenthelp.secure.griffith.edu.au/app/answers/detail/a_id/177/%7E/i-have-a-class-timetable-clash.-what-should-i-do%3F) in addition to British).